# Find xpath of attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div class="half">
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="half" id="label">Memory Color</div>
        <div class="half" id="value">BLACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="half" id="label">LED Lighting</div>
        <div class="half" id="value">RGB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="half" id="label">Single Zone / Multi-Zone Lighting</div>
        <div class="half" id="value">Dynamic Multi-Zone</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I find the xpath for the `value` text of one of the `list-item`s by specifying the `label` text? For example, how would I return the `value` text (`BLACK`) given the `LABEL` text is `Memory Color` (without using the position that `BLACK` and `Memory Color` are in the list, so not using `div[1]`, but finding it by specifying `Memory Color`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/div/div[@class='list-item' and div[@id='label']='Memory Color']/div[@id='value']
```

It results in `BLACK` as output. Of course you can change the constant `Memory Color` to the string you want.